# conditional based upon the count of current user's published custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags, count

I have this conditional snippet that does something is the current user has not published a normal post. But I'd like to change it so that it counts a custom post rather than a normal post.

```
<?php if ( 0 == count_user_posts( get_current_user_id() ) && is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
do something
<?php } else { ?>
do something else
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is what I have tried...

```
<?php if ( 0 == count_user_posts( get_current_user_id(), "CUSTOM_POST_TYPE" ) && is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
do something
<?php } else { ?>
do something else
<?php } ?>
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing it seems my attempt (in my question) works!

```
<?php if ( 0 == count_user_posts( get_current_user_id(), "CUSTOM_POST_TYPE" ) && is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
do something
<?php } else { ?>
do something else
<?php } ?>
```